# What is the right solution for Menu from database => base view model for layout vs model in httpcontext ()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out what is the right solution for creating a menu in a ASP.NET. The menu has items and subitems and are subject to user rights. So I have a MenuService that returns the menu for the current user. However I do not know how to implement the menu.

So far I have found 3 possible solutions:

1. Define a base view model to add on the Layout, and every page view model should derived from this (This would mean that the IMenuService needs to be on every controller)
2. Use a base controller where I attach the IMenuService and that is going to be attached to the HttpContext.Items before every action (based on this https://dtoncode.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/strongly-typed-models-on-your-layout/)
3. Define a Controller for menu and in layout call a partial view to place the menu on it.

Which of these solutions are the right one for the job? Are there others?

Comment: All of then will work. Asking for opinions is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: I know they work but I am new to web development and could not find reasons to use one solution over the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`MvcSiteMapProvider`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for this - it is very similar to the [Web Forms SiteMap provider model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), but made for MVC.

Basically, the entire `SiteMap` hierarchy is loaded into a cache and shared between users. You can configure the nodes in many ways - to load them from a database, you can use one or more [dynamic node providers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider). It has a [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming) feature that automatically reads the `[Authorize]` attribute on each request and changes visibility of individual items accordingly.

The menu and breadcrumb HTML helpers it uses are templated, so you can change them to output any HTML you need.

**Full Disclosure:** I made a major contribution to this project.